# Dynamic height of header with multiline UILabel in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I found solution to get dynamic header height in UITableView by setting

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

I get the effect that the header is set to the height of one UILabel line, while it should be set to the height of all lines.
I have two UILabels in a HorizontalStackView. When one of the UILabel is more than one line long then automatic height adjustment does not work. I've tried to set

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

in some starting methonds but nothing worked.

Comment: Do you have access to the text in ViewController that will be display in header? If yes you can calculate the frame for that text and can return height of that frame.

Comment: We need to see the code of your `two UILabels in a HorizontalStackView`, it is probably a constraint issue.

Comment: @Aafaq I dont have access to viewcontroller

Comment: @NicolasElPapu It's super easy view. One HorizontalStackView with constraints all around it pinned to superview (content view). No more constraints in view. Inside StackView I have two labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have got your Section Header setup using a XIB file, it is probably a constraint issue that is causing incorrect sizes, among other things.

I have put together a list of common errors that can happen when working with dynamic section headers. Please check them one-by-one, to see which one resolves your issue.

### 1. Make sure your Constraints are setup correctly.

Open up your Section Header XIB and make sure that there are enough constraints for `UITableView` to calculate the view's height. Notice that I have setup the bottom constraint with a priority of 999. This is important because of Step 3.

[image]

### 2. Make sure your `UILabel` can grow

Set the "Number of Lines" of both `UILabel`s to zero as shown below.

[image]

### 3. Adjust the Content Hugging and Compression Resistance

Select your UILabels, and click the "Size Inspector" ([image]).

At the bottom, set these values to 1000 so that Auto Layout treats them as important as your other constraints.

- Content Hugging Priority > Vertical

This sets how well the `UILabel`'s height should hugs its text content.

- Compression Resistance Priority > Vertical

This sets how much the `UILabel` should resist shrinking its height beyond the height of its content.

Like so:

[image]

### 4. Return a reasonable value in `estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection`

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0
}
```

### 5. Compile and run!

Your section headers should now be properly sizing.

[image]

### Notes:

1. Make sure your data source is not random text that doesn't depend on the section index.
2. If your section headers overlap or are improperly sized, make sure that your data source isn't changing while the `UITableView` is scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

step 1: calculate the height of both `UILabel` text in `heightForHeaderInSection` method.

step 2: return the max height in `heightForHeaderInSection`.

and make sure to set `UILabel`'s `numberOfLines` property to 0.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23)
    let height1 = "section \(section) label1 text".height(withConstrainedWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 , font: font)  
    let height2 =  "section \(section) label2 text".height(withConstrainedWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 , font: font) 
    return max(height1,height2)
}
```

Here I'm using an extension of `String` to calculate the height of the `UILabel` text.

```
extension String {
    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
    
        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }
}
```